# Build dynamic grid using jquery mobile and modulus

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, laravel-blade

I'm try to build a dynamic grid using php and jquery mobile.   I would like to know if anyone can help me to use modulus to determine if the ui-block- needs to be a-d depending on the key value of the iteration.

```
  <div class="ui-grid-c">
        @forelse($photos as $key=>$photo)

            @if($key == 1)
                <div class="ui-block-a">                                
                    <img src="{{ $photo['file'] }}" width="60" />
                </div>
            @elseif($key == 2)
                <div class="ui-block-b">                                
                    <img src="{{ $photo['file'] }}" width="60" />
                </div>
            @elseif($key == 3)
                <div class="ui-block-c">                                
                    <img src="{{ $photo['file'] }}" width="60" />
                </div>
            @elseif($key == 4)
                <div class="ui-block-d">                                
                    <img src="{{ $photo['file'] }}" width="60" />
                </div>  
            @endif

        @empty

            Nothing Found

        @endforelse
    </div>
```

I've tried a few different modulus variations, but nothing worked right.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You meed to modify your ui-grid-c class to be dynamic based on the number of columns.

- ui-grid-a = 2 columns
- ui-grid-b = 3 columns
- ui-grid-c = 4 columns
- ect.

for your columns..

- ui-block-a - is your first column
- ui-block-b - is your second colum
- ect.

So you'll need to keep track of th number of times you added in columns, and then add in the alphabet letter.

Using  will give you the character a and then just increment 86 for other characters as you add columns.